# Can't extract src attribute from "img" tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup, src

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to extract the pictures' URL from a website. I'm a noob at this so please bear with me. Based on the HTML code, the class of the pictures that I want is "fotorama__img". However, when I execute my code, it doesn't seem to work. Anyone knows why that's the case? Also, how come the `src` attribute doesn't contain the whole URL, just a part of it? Example: the link to the image is `https://www.supermicro.com/files_SYS/images/System/SYS-120U-TNR_callout_front.jpg` but the `src` attribute of the `img` tag is `"/files_SYS/images/System/sysThumb/SYS-120U-TNR_main.png"`.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

page = requests.get("https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/system/Ultra/1U/SYS-120U-TNR")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
images = soup.find_all("img", {"class": "fotorama__img"})
for image in images:
    print(image.get("src"))
```

And here is the picture of the HTML code for the page
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is added dynamically via JavaScript, so beautifulsoup doesn't see it. To extract the images from this site, you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(
    "https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/system/Ultra/1U/SYS-120U-TNR"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
images = [
    "https://www.supermicro.com" + a["href"]
    for a in soup.select(".fotorama > a")
]

print(*images, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
https://www.supermicro.com/files_SYS/images/System/SYS-120U-TNR_main.png
https://www.supermicro.com/files_SYS/images/System/SYS-120U-TNR_callout_angle.jpg
https://www.supermicro.com/files_SYS/images/System/SYS-120U-TNR_callout_top.jpg
https://www.supermicro.com/files_SYS/images/System/SYS-120U-TNR_callout_front.jpg
https://www.supermicro.com/files_SYS/images/System/SYS-120U-TNR_callout_rear.jpg
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you for your speedy comment. May I ask why you used `href` instead of `src` and what does `(".fotorama >a")` mean?

Comment: @JakeNguyen When you do `print(soup)` you will see that the full images are inside `<a>` tags in `href=` attribute. The `".fotorama > a"` is CSS selector: it means "give me all `<a>` tags that are directly under tags with `class="fotorama"`.

Comment: I see. When I used the Inspect function on Google Chrome, it didn't show the <a> tag that wraps around the <img> tag so I was a little confused. Still so many things to learn. Thanks a lot man.